# Unset keys in an array with matching values in another array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I unset the keys in one array where the values contained in a second array match the values in the first array?

---

**Actual array:**

```
$fruits = array('Banana','Cherry','Orange','Apple');
```

**Elements I want to remove:**

```
$remove = array('Banana','Apple');
```

**Need to return:**

```
$array = array('Cherry','Orange');
```

---

I know it's possible to remove each one with `unset`, but I'm looking to make it in one line with two array.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by *in one line with 2 arrays* ?

Comment: I do not want to have 2 or more `unset(...)`.

Comment: is not the answer of @tiganion what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this function
[link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$arrayWithoutTheDesiredElements = array_diff($originalArr, $toRemoveArray)
```

**EDIT:**

for your case: `$array = array_diff($fruits, $remove);`